# can css hide unchecked radio buttons? or it's indicator/border?

Tags: css, input

I'm trying to hide radio botton's indicator's when its unchecked.
I've tried the following css (together and seperate):

```
input[type=radio]:unchecked, input:unchecked {
  border:none; visibility:hidden; display:none
}
```

Is it possible to hide the circle border of the indicator's input radio/chechbox by using css ?

thanks.

Comment: my solution (for now): i put the all radio buttons opacity 0 and the :checked with opacity 1. now i have dificult with :hover... hope to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a custom look and feel for the radio buttons I will suggest to rely on css background-images to replace the radio buttons with a custom design, something like in this tutorial that also cover accessibility

http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201211/accessible_custom_checkboxes_and_radio_buttons/

Via css you can't just hide or modify part of the radio button

Comment: it's too complicate. my solution: put the all radio buttons opacity 0 and the :checked with opacity 1.